# Maven can't download scribe 1.3.6 in a project with multiple repositories

Tags: java, maven, scribe

I created a simple maven project with a scribe 1.3.6 dependency, in order for that to work I followed intstructions at https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java and added following to my pom.xml

```
<!-- repository -->
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>scribe-java-mvn-repo</id>
    <url>https://raw.github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/mvn-repo/</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<!-- dependency -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scribe</groupId>
  <artifactId>scribe</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

This works without problem.

When I try to include scribe into another project where I already have other repositories, then download does not happen

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>hippo</id>
        <name>Hippo maven 2 repository.</name>
        <url>http://maven.onehippo.com/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>hippo-maven2-enterprise</id>
        <name>Hippo Enterprise Maven 2</name>
        <url>https://maven.onehippo.com/maven2-enterprise</url>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
    <!-- scribe repository-->
    <repository>
        <id>scribe-java-mvn-repo</id>
        <url>https://raw.github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/mvn-repo/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

</repositories>
```

In the build output I can see Downloading trace, but no **Downloaded**:

```
Downloading: https://raw.github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/mvn-repo/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.pom
Downloading: http://maven.onehippo.com/maven2/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.pom
Downloading: https://maven.onehippo.com/maven2-enterprise/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.pom
Jun 25, 2014 7:03:47 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor selectAuthScheme
INFO: basic authentication scheme selected
Downloading: http://maven.onehippo.com/maven2-forge/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.scribe:scribe:jar:1.3.6 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://raw.github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/mvn-repo/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.jar
Downloading: http://maven.onehippo.com/maven2/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.jar
Downloading: https://maven.onehippo.com/maven2-enterprise/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.jar
Jun 25, 2014 7:03:49 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor selectAuthScheme
INFO: basic authentication scheme selected
Downloading: http://maven.onehippo.com/maven2-forge/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.jar
```

In the project with only the scribe repository, I can see the ,  **Downloaded** traces:

```
Downloading: https://raw.github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/mvn-repo/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.pom
Downloaded: https://raw.github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/mvn-repo/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.pom (4 KB at 1.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.pom
Downloading: https://raw.github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/mvn-repo/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.jar
Downloaded: https://raw.github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/mvn-repo/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.jar (89 KB at 43.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.jar
```

Comment: in the case where download isn't working, can you check if repository is listed by `mvn help:effective-help` ?

Comment: yes doing mvn help:effective-pom, I can get see the repository. It's also shown in the maven output

Comment: The raw.github and maven.onehippo.com repositories seemed to be not working and 1.3.6 is not available from maven central only 1.3.5. You should contact the author.

Comment: Raw.github works in a pom.xml where it is the only repository